# The eigenvalues of the product $WD$ for some particular matrices

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, eigenvalues, eigenvector

Let $D$ be a diagonal matrix  in $M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $D^2=I$ and Trace$(D)$=0

Suppose that  $e_k$s are the standard vectors  in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, that is
$$e_k=(0,\cdots 0,1,0,\cdots,0)^t$$ where $1$  is in the $k^{th}$ position.
Let us consider the following vectors for $k=1,\cdots,n$.

$$v_k=e_{2k}~~,~~~ v_{n+k}=e_{2k-1}$$

Let us consider the matrix $W$ whose $k^{th}$-coulmn $W_k$ is given by  $v_k$

Q. How can we find the eigenvalues of $WD$?

Comment: Yes, It was just edited.

Comment: Yes. Moreover,  based on the spectral theory,  all the  eigenvalues  of  $WD$ are in the unit circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that the $n\times n$ matrix $M=WD$ is "periodic", $M^p=\pm M$ for some even integer $p\leq n$. This identifies the eigenvalues of $M$ as $p$-th roots of $\pm 1$.

For some $n$ I find $p=n$ and the eigenvalues are all distinct: $e^{2k\pi i/n}$ if $M^n=M$ or $e^{(2k+1)\pi i/n}$ if $M^n=-M$, with $k=0,1,2,\ldots n-1$. This is the case for $n=2,4,6,10,12$.

But for other $n$ I find $p<n$, and some eigenvalues have multiplicity greater than 1. This happens for $n=8$ (with $p=6$) and for $n=14$ (with $p=8$). I have not been able to find the rule that governs these cases.

Comment: Great argument.